# Python requests_html submit a form by clicking a button using JQuery

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, python-requests-html

I'm exploring [Kenneth Reitz's requests_html](https://html.python-requests.org/) and trying to submit a form of a JS Rendered Webpage using Jquery. I'm not sure how to do it but, here is my attempt:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
url = "https://example.com"
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render()
script = """
       () => {
         $("#some_input_field").val("Some value");
         $("#submit_button").click();
         }
         """
r.html.render(script=script, reload=False)
```

But, the value is not getting set on the input field & it isn't submitting the form... 
Is there any way to simulate button click or, form submit via `xhr` in requests_html?

For example: If we use selenium we can simulate button click pretty easily by typing:

```
element.click()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, The following code is working in my case:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
url = "https://example.com"
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render()
script = """
       () => {
              if ( jQuery.isReady ) {  
                   $("#some_input_field").val("Some value");
                   $("#submit_button").click();
              }
        }
         """
r.html.render(script=script, reload=False)
```

**EDIT:** A better approach should be:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
url = "https://example.com"
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render()
script = """
       () => {
              $(document).ready(function() {  
                   $("#some_input_field").val("Some value");
                   $("#submit_button").click();
              })
        }
         """
r.html.render(script=script, reload=False)
```

Comment: Hey very much appreciate seeing this, could you please explain why and how the part after `script=` works?

Comment: @JasonGoal `script` variable is a string containing JavaScript code. It fills an input field and clicks the submit button. [()=>{}](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#comparing_traditional_functions_to_arrow_functions) is an arrow function. The dollar sign in the second function is [JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/ready/#ready-handler)

Comment: @Wasi Can you explain what `document` refers to in the second code snippit? I get the following error when I try to run (and have replaced the `some_input_field` and `submit_button`...: pyppeteer.errors.ElementHandleError: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: $ is not defined...

Comment: My script is as follows: 
```
    script = """
           () => {
                  $(document).ready(function() {  
                       $("#publish-to-mobile-button").click();
                       $("#publish-to-mobile-confirm-button").click();
                  })
            }
             """
```

Comment: UPDATE: I figured it out with the help of https://github.com/psf/requests-html/issues/355#issuecomment-942914999

Answer (score 0):

**The below statements were not made by me but were helpful in resolving. Credit to alairjunior's response on this [issue](https://github.com/psf/requests-html/issues/355#issuecomment-942914999)**

I wasn't able to use the 'load' and 'DOMContentLoaded' events. Did not investigate why yet. I suspect the script is run using the "console", so it cannot get those events. But this is just a wild guess.

For a quick and dirty solution, I was able to use setTimeout:

```
script = """
() => {
setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelectorAll("a")[2].click();
}, 3000);
}
"""
```

If I use `r.html.render(sleep=10,script=script)` I am able to get the content of the page after the click was executed.

Hope this is useful.