# Click Yahoo finance button with html_requests

Tags: python, jquery

Through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54889023/python-requests-html-submit-a-form-by-clicking-a-button-using-jquery), I learned that html_requests can be used to click html buttons. I am trying to read the entire balance sheet table on Yahoo Finance ([Link](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/balance-sheet)) by clicking the "Expanded all" button with the code I have provided. However, the click action does not seem to be successful.

I know selenium is a possible solution.

```
ticker='AAPL'
report='balance-sheet'
url=f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{ticker}/{report}'
session = AsyncHTMLSession()
r = await session.get(url)
r.html.arender()
script = """
    () => {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".expandPf.Fz(s).Bd(0).C($linkColor).C($linkActiveColor):h.Fw(500).D(n)--print.Fl(end).Mt(5px)").click();
        });
    }
    """
r.html.arender(script=script, reload=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.html.html, 'html.parser')
soup_data=soup.find('div', {'id': 'Col1-1-Financials-Proxy'}).find('div', {'class': 'D(tbrg)'})
await session.close()

data=[[j.text for j in i.find_all('div', {'data-test': 'fin-col'})] for i in soup_data.find_all('div', {'data-test': 'fin-row'})]
```

My code cannot extract hte "hided data" in the table. I expect the second record is Current Assets' figures instead of Total Liabilities Net Minority's.